# Django on Android pydroid3.Python and Django are fully functional. But when I try to run Django admin site on Chrome it shows "Server error occured"

Tags: python, django, frameworks

This is what am facing with with Django on my Android I'm using Pydroid on my phone. Python and Django are fully functional. But when I try to run Django admin site on Chrome it shows "Server error occurred. Contact administrator"

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

April 28, 2022 - 16:28:28

Django version 4.0.4, using settings 'mysite.settings'

Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

[28/Apr/2022 16:28:45] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

[28/Apr/2022 16:28:55] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/zoneinfo/_common.py", line 12, in load_tzdata

```
return importlib.resources.open_binary(package_name, resource_name)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/resources.py", line 88, in open_binary

```
package = _get_package(package)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/resources.py", line 49, in _get_package

```
module = _resolve(package)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/resources.py", line 40, in _resolve

```
return import_module(name)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module

```
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
```

File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import

File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load

File "", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import

File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load

File "", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import

File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load

File "", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tzdata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner

```
response = get_response(request)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in _get_response

```
response = response.render()
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 114, in render

```
self.content = self.rendered_content
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 92, in rendered_content

```
return template.render(context, self._request)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 62, in render

```
return self.template.render(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render

```
return self._render(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render

```
return self.nodelist.render(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render

```
return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in

```
return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 958, in render_annotated

```
return self.render(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 157, in render

```
return compiled_parent._render(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render

```
return self.nodelist.render(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render

```
return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in

```
return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 958, in render_annotated

```
return self.render(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 157, in render

```
return compiled_parent._render(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render

```
return self.nodelist.render(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render

```
return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in

```
return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 958, in render_annotated

```
return self.render(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 389, in render

```
tzinfo = timezone.get_current_timezone() if settings.USE_TZ else None
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 84, in get_current_timezone

```
return getattr(_active, "value", get_default_timezone())
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 70, in get_default_timezone

```
return zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(settings.TIME_ZONE)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/zoneinfo/_common.py", line 24, in load_tzdata

```
raise ZoneInfoNotFoundError(f"No time zone found with key {key}")
```

zoneinfo._common.ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key Africa/Lagos'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/zoneinfo/_common.py", line 12, in load_tzdata

```
return importlib.resources.open_binary(package_name, resource_name)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/resources.py", line 88, in open_binary

```
package = _get_package(package)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/resources.py", line 49, in _get_package

```
module = _resolve(package)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/resources.py", line 40, in _resolve

```
return import_module(name)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module

```
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
```

File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import

File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load

File "", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import

File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load

File "", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import

File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load

File "", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tzdata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner

```
response = get_response(request)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 134, in **call**

```
response = response or self.get_response(request)  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 57, in inner

response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 139, in response_for_exception

```
response = handle_uncaught_exception(
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 180, in handle_uncaught_exception

```
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 66, in technical_500_response

```
html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 386, in get_traceback_html

```
return t.render(c)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render

```
return self._render(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render

```
return self.nodelist.render(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render

```
return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in

```
return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 958, in render_annotated

```
return self.render(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1059, in render

```
output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 735, in resolve

```
obj = template_localtime(obj, context.use_tz)
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 184, in template_localtime

```
return localtime(value) if should_convert else value
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 203, in localtime

```
timezone = get_current_timezone()
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 84, in get_current_timezone

```
return getattr(_active, "value", get_default_timezone())
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 70, in get_

```
default_timezone

    return zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(settings.TIME_ZONE)

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/zoneinfo/_common.py", line 24, in load_tzdata
```

Comment: This code is terrible to read. Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it. It will others help understanding your question and give you maybe help. The way it is written, it is more unlikely that someone will take the time and look into it.